# Linguagem Java - Funções Undo e Redo

Tags: java, imagem

Estou a fazer um projeto em que desenvolvo funções para aplicar efeitos a fotos (como o Contrast, Vignette, Sepia...).

A medida que aplico efeitos às fotos, os vários estados das fotos vão sendo guardados num vetor de imagens.

Nesse mesmo projeto, necessito de duas funções, a Undo e a Redo. A Undo servirá para obter a foto com o efeito anteriormente aplicado e a Redo servirá para obter de novo o ultimo efeito aplicado.

Alguém me consegue ajudar no desenvolvimento destas funções (Undo e Redo)?

Obrigado.

**Aqui está o que tenho na classe:**

```
class Historico {

    private ColorImage [] VCI;
    private int atual;
    boolean undo = false;
    private int undos;
    private int redos;

    public Historico(ColorImage [] VCI) {
        this.VCI = VCI;
        atual = 0;
        undos = 0;
        redos = 0;
    }

    static ColorImage copy (ColorImage CI) {
        ColorImage NCI = new ColorImage(CI.getWidth(),CI.getHeight());
        for(int x = 0; x < CI.getWidth(); x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < CI.getHeight(); y++){
                Color c = CI.getColor(x,y);
                NCI.setColor(x,y,c);
                }
            }
        return NCI;
        } 

    void saveImage(ColorImage CI) {
        VCI [atual] = copy(CI);
        atual++;
        undo = false;
        undos = 0;
        redos=0;
    }

    public void undo() {
        ColorImage CI = copy(VCI[atual-2-undos]);
        VCI[atual] = CI;
        atual = atual + 1;
        undo = true;
        undos = undos + 2;
    }

    public void redo() {
        if(undo = true) {
            ColorImage CI = copy(VCI[atual-2-redos]);
            VCI[atual] = CI;
            atual = atual + 1; 
            undos--;
            if(undos<0){
                undos = 0;
                undo = false;
            }
            redos = redos + 2;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Já ouviu falar do padrão de projeto [**memento**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)?

Comment: Olá Victor Stafusa. Não ouvi falar. Já consegui fazer a função Undo. A minha função Redo consigo aplicá-la 2 vezes mas à terceira deixa de funcionar (não acontece mesmo nada), consegue me ajudar? Se necessário eu copio o código que já tenho das 2 funções. Obrigado

Comment: Sim, é recomendável você postar o seu código: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/132

Comment: Ok, peço desculpa. Acabei de editar a pergunta e já lá está o código que tenho na classe. O que está a funcionar mal é a função Redo (consigo utilizá-la 2 vezes mas à terceira deixa de funcionar (passa a não acontecer nada))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar duas listas como se fossem pilhas, uma para o "undo" e uma para o "redo". Além disso, ao usar listas ao invés de arrays, as coisas vão ficar muito mais simples de se trabalhar.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Historico {

    private final List<ColorImage> undos;
    private final List<ColorImage> redos;
    private ColorImage atual;

    public Historico() {
        this.undos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.redos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.atual = emBranco();
    }

    private static ColorImage emBranco() {
        return new ColorImage(256, 256);
    } 

    private static ColorImage copy(ColorImage ci) {
        ColorImage nci = new ColorImage(ci.getWidth(), ci.getHeight());
        for (int x = 0; x < ci.getWidth(); x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < ci.getHeight(); y++) {
                Color c = ci.getColor(x, y);
                nci.setColor(x, y, c);
            }
        }
        return nci;
    } 

    public void saveImage(ColorImage ci) {
        undos.add(atual);
        redos.clear();
        atual = ci;
    }

    public ColorImage undo() {
        if (!undos.isEmpty()) {
            redos.add(atual);
            atual = undos.remove(undos.size() - 1);
        }
        return atual;
    }

    public ColorImage redo() {
        if (!redos.isEmpty()) {
            undos.add(atual);
            atual = redos.remove(redos.size() - 1);
        }
        return atual;
    }

    public ColorImage getAtual() {
        return atual;
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Victor Stafusa! Ajudou imenso! Muito obrigado. Os meus cumprimentos.

Answer (score 0):

Você informou que os estados das fotos a cada modificação são guardados em um vetor de imagens, correto? Acredito que seu trabalho seria simplificado se, ao invés de utilizar um vetor, você utilizasse uma lista duplamente encadeada ([LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)). Como ela possui referências tanto para o estado anterior quanto ao posterior da sua imagem, a implementação de suas funções Redo e Undo poderiam ser simplificadas somente à movimentação do ponteiro que indica a posição atual na sua lista através dos métodos Previous e Next de um [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Comment: Olá Marcos Andrade. Desde já obrigado pela sua colaboração. Acontece que ainda não aprendi a utilizar a tal lista duplamente encadeada, mas acredito que seria uma boa solução.

Comment: Entendo. Você tem conhecimento da lógica de funcionamento de uma lista encadeada? Se sim, não é muito difícil montar manualmente uma lista duplamente encadeada, que funciona de forma bem simples e resolveria o seu problema. Posso te ajudar com isso se tiver interesse. Se você está na faculdade, é até interessante porque isso costuma cair bastante em estruturas de dados.

Comment: Marcos, mediante o código que meti (editei a pergunta) ainda acha que seria mais simples ?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Sinceramente, a maior vantagem que você poderia tirar dessa solução seria melhoria semântica no seu código. Ele possui variáveis de "controle de versão" (undos e redos) que são desnecessárias se você utilizar uma estrutura de dados mais adequada, e isso pode causar grandes dificuldades caso você queira expandir o codigo mais à frente adicionando mais funcionalidades ou utilizando como parte de outro projeto. Se você nao planeja expandir o código mais à frente, é OK manter ele desse modo, mas eu chego a considerar isso uma certa gambiarra... haha

Comment: Obrigado pela atencao Marcos. Nao tenciono expandir mais codigo, aliás Marcos esta classe é mesmo o final do meu projeto. O que me pedem é isto, até porque comecei à pouco tempo. Sendo assim, com o código que eu escrevi, o que me avonselhas a modificar para a função Redo dar certo Marcos?